# Error occurs when jQuery processing a form is inside another form

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, forms

I am writing a form using jQuery and encounter some difficulties.

My form works fine in static page (html).
However, when I use the form in dynamic page(aspx), the form does not behave correctly.
I cannot append items to the form and call the form.serialize function.

I think the error occurs when a form is inside another form (.aspx code needs to enclosed by a form tag).

What should I do?

Let me give a simplified version of my code:

```
<form name="Form1" method="post" id="Form1">
some content
<form name="form_inside">
<input name="fname" type="text" />
</form>
</form>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("#form_inside").append($("<input type='text' name='lname'>"));
```

When the user submits,

```
$("#form_inside").serialize(); 
// it should return fname=inputfname&lname=inputlname
```

I want to append element to "form_inside" and serialize the form "form_inside".
The form "Form1" is required by the aspx and I cannot remove it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post some code and give some kind of indication as to what it does or what errors are generated.  Specifically, if you can provide a VERY simple example of some ASPX/HTML and jQuery code that demonstrates the problem...

Comment: Note that you cannot have nested <form> elements in an HTML page.

Comment: An example is added to the question. Thanks.

Comment: I know I should not have nested <form> element. But in my situation, what can I do when aspx needs to have a <form> element in the very beginning of the page.?

Comment: Then I think you have to use *that* form element.  Then choose other ways to coordinate your interesting form elements, such as by tagging them with a marker css class or something to make them easily selectable.

Comment: Post that as an answer, Chris. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just serialize the fields inside `Form1`?

I don't know anything about ASP, but it seems that you're not doing a straightforward "submit" anyway - so does it really matter if the fields aren't within their own separate form?

You could possibly group the fields you're interested in within a `<div>` or something, e.g.:

```
<div id="my-interesting-fields">
    ...
</div>
```

then substitute `#form-inside` with `#my-interesting-fields` where appropriate - is that helpful at all?

#### Edit

OK, a quick glance at the jQuery code suggests that `serialize()` depends on the form's `elements` member.

I suppose you could hack this in a couple of different ways:

- Copy all elements from `#my-interesting-fields` into a temporary `<form>` that you dynamically create outside `Form1`, then call `serialize()` on that. Something like:

  ```
  $("#Form1").after("<form id='tmp-form'></form>").
              append("#my-interesting-fields input");
  $("tmp-form").serialize();
  ```
- Or, create an `elements` member on `#my-interesting-fields`, e.g.

  ```
  $("#my-interesting-fields").elements = $("#my-interesting-fields input");
  $("#my-interesting-fields").serialize();
  ```

I haven't tried either of these, but that might give you a couple of ideas. Not that I would necessarily recommend either of them :)

Comment: I can't serialize the form element inside "my-interesting-fields".

Comment: I try to serialize it by $("#my-interesting-fields > input").serialize(). It doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm. It seems that serialize() might only work on form elements. You could possibly try copying the fields into a 'temporary' form?

Comment: The first method works. I usually the following code:
$("<form></form>").append($("#my-interesting-fields *")).serialize()

I don't quite understand the 2nd method.

Comment: Second method is an ugly hack that depends on the internal implementation of serialize() - I would avoid it. The code is basically making the div look like a form (to fool jQuery). Glad the first method works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't have nested <form> tags you'll need to close off the standard dotnet form tag like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form_inside").append($("<input type='text' name='lname'>"));
        $("#submitBtn").click(function() {function() {
            var obj = $("#form_inside *");
            var values = new Array();
            obj.each(function(i,obj1) {
                if (obj1.name && !obj1.disabled && obj1.value) {
                    values.push(obj1);
                }; 
                });
                alert(jQuery.param(values));
        }); });
    });

</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<div id="form_inside" name="form_inside"> <input name="fname" type="text" /><input type="button" id="submitBtn" /></div>

</div>
</form>
```

jQuery.param on a array of form elements will give you the same results as .serialize()

so you get all elements in div $("#form_inside *) then filter for elements then on the result jQuery.param will give you exactly what you need

Comment: Due to the structure and code of the webpage, I cannot move it out from the dotnet form tag.